# O que significa o erro "Execução de scripts foi desabilitada neste sistema"?

Tags: windows, powershell

Eu estava testando algumas coisas do `PowerShell ISE` pra poder montar uns scripts.

Percebi que, enquanto eu executava o script sem salvar o arquivo, os comandos eram executados normalmente. Porém, logo após ter salvo o arquivo na área de trabalho, a execução do mesmo passou a gerar o seguinte erro:

> O arquivo *script.ps1* não pode ser carregado porque a
>    execução de scripts foi desabilitada neste sistema.
>
> Consulte "get-help about_si
>   gning" para obter mais detalhes.
>   At line:0 char:0

Mas eu não desabilitei nada...

De que "habilitação" o Windows está falando? Como posso ativar a execução de scripts PowerShell no Windows?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Isto é uma política de segurança do Powershell para evitar que *scripts* maliciosos sejam executados indevidamente no seu sistema. Por isso, todos os *scripts* que não forem assinados terão sua execução bloqueada. Ou seja, a política de execução está como `Restricted` (que é o padrão).

Você pode controlar estas permissões usando o *cmdlet* `Set-ExecutionPolicy`. E pode conferir qual a política de execução atual usando o *cmdlet* `Get-ExecutionPolicy`.

> ```
> PS C:\Users\LINQ> Get-ExecutionPolicy
> Restricted
>
> PS C:\Users\LINQ> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
> PS C:\Users\LINQ> Get-ExecutionPolicy
> RemoteSigned
> ```

Existem vários tipos de permissão que você pode usar com este *cmdlet*

#### Restricted

Não carrega nem executa arquivos de configuração e/ou *scripts* do Powershell.

#### AllSigned

Só executa *scripts* e arquivos de configuração assinados por um fornecedor confiável, mesmo que o *script* tenha sido escrito por você mesmo (local).

#### RemoteSigned

É basicamente o mesmo que o acima, porém permite a execução de arquivos de configuração e/ou *scripts* locais.

#### Unrestricted

Carrega e executa todos os arquivos de configuração e *scripts* PowerShell. Pode ser pedida uma confirmação para executar *scripts* não assinados.

#### Bypass

Não há nenhuma restrição.

#### Undefined

Remove a política de execução atual. A não ser que ela esteja definida numa diretiva de grupo.

Answer (score 24):

Por padrão o privilégio para excutar scripts é o `Restricted`, ou seja, nenhum script chamado via arquivo pode ser executado apenas em modo interativo (via console ou ISE)

Para alterar a politica de execução use o cmdlet e algum dos seguinte

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned
```

`Restricted`: É valor padrão (Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, and Windows 8.1) , não permite que nenhum arquivo seja executado isso inclui arquivos de configuração (.ps1xml), módulos (.psm1) e .ps1

`AllSigned`: Permite a execução de arquivos, porém necessita que os arquivos sejam assinados por um publicador confiável.

`Unrestricted`: Scripts não assinados podem rodar.

`Bypass`: Nada é bloqueado e não emite warnings ou prompts (pergunta se deseja executar algo por exemplo)

`Undefined`: Define a politica de execução indefinida. Se todos os escopos forem `Undefined` por padrão ela vira `Restricted`. Pode verificar os diferentes níveis com:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -list
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx)

[About Execution Policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies)

Answer (score 21):

Uma alternativa de corrigir o problema é executar o comando abaixo dentro do Prompt de Comando

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`

No meu caso eu estava acontecendo quando eu tentava executar o comando `ng s` para iniciar a aplicação do Angular.

Executando o comando acima o problema não foi mais apresentado!

Comment: Funcionou aqui. muito obrigado!

Comment: boa, deu certo também

Answer (score 4):

É possível também alterar os valores via chave de registro (`regedit` ou comando `reg` no `cmd`):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell]
"ExecutionPolicy"="bypass"
```

Salve as linhas acima como `liberar.reg`, e abra, ou use o comando `reg import liberar.reg`

Comment: Crítica construtiva: O que "bypass" faz?

Answer (score -2):

Using powerShell(ADM) can you change the terminal configuration with this command:

```
IN powerShell(ADM)
1(Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass)
2(select "Yes For All (A)")
```

Answer (score -3):

Utilizando [cmder](https://cmder.net/) como administrador é possível contornar isso.

Answer (score -4):

Abrir o prompt do Windows Power Shell como administrador.

Executar o comando:
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Comment: A pergunta é "O que significa o erro “Execução de scripts foi desabilitada neste sistema”?", esse é um campo de resposta que você usou e não de comentário, se não responde a pergunta então não é uma resposta. Não somos uma fórum, somos um site de PERGUNTAS e RESPOSTAS definitivas ou complementares, mas elas devem sempre serem explicadas.

Comment: ok, a intenção era somente ajudar... pois ja passei pelo mesmo problema...

Repare na ultiam pergunta feita: 
"Como posso ativar a execução de scripts PowerShell no Windows?"

abcs!!!

Comment: Torno a dizer o que sempre digo para quem esta iniciando no site, não somos um fórum e este campo "publique sua resposta" é para resolver o problema da pergunta e não para comentar coisas, se não resolve completamente ou não é complemento da resposta de outra pessoa então não é o lugar que deva usar, imagine alguém chegar na sua casa ou sua empresa novo, não ler as regras e começar a bagunçar tudo, então é isto, leia as regras, somos uma boa comunidade e entender como funciona para participar é respeitar a comunidade. Seja bem vindo Marlon.