# Erro no prompt de comando do VSCODE

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando carregar as informações do codigo pelo prompt de comando do VSCODE e não está executando, alguem sabe como reseolver?[Imagem do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P39Aw.png)

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220078/o-que-significa-o-erro-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-scripts-foi-desabilitada-neste-sistema

Answer (score -3):

Altera o seu terminal de powershell para cmd e refaça o procedimento.

Ou se quiser, aperte ctrl + shift + c que irá abrir um prompt do cmd e você executa o seu script.